# Windows Phone - How to handle navigation errors

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

How should I handle navigation errors if they occur in the OnNavigatedTo method. For example, a query string parameter is not passed or throws an exception while parsing to an integer.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string itemIdParam;

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("itemId", out itemIdParam))
        {
            int itemId = int.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["itemId"]);

            _item = App.MainViewModel.Items.Where(i => i.ItemId == itemId).First();

            DataContext = _item;
        }
    }
```

Should I catch them and display a MessageBox or let them

Comment: Well, whatever? It's up to you to decide how your app should react to errors.

Comment: Sure, maybe there's an recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
if( this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("itemId"))
  {
      string s_itemid = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["itemId"];
      int i_itemid;
      bool result = Int32.TryParse(s_itemid, out i_itemid);
      if(result)
         //parsing success
      else
         //parsing error

  }
else
   //parameter doesn't exist
```

More information about TryParse: [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Comment: I know the TryParse method but the question is how to handle this case. For example, if I show a MessageBox it will block the execution. I don't know if that is good style.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do to reduce the error is to define your navigation uri.
For example in Details.xaml page you can create a static method called GetUri() with parameters of wanted type.

```
public static Uri GetUri(int itemId){
  return new Uri(string.Format("/Details.xaml?itemId={0}", itemId), UriKind.Relative);
}
```

When you want to navigate to Details page just write:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(Details.GetUri(2));
```